# Why Do PhpUnit dataProviders Lower Coverage Scores?

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, php-code-coverage

I have been using PhpUnit with good results, testing my code with assertions only. Recently I decided to try PhpUnit with coverage report analysis but I noticed that tests that use dataProvider methods tend to decrease my code coverage scores. I wonder what I might be doing wrong or if this is a consequence of dataProvider testing techniques? I am using PhpUnit 6 with Php 7.

I have included a source class, Foo, with three test classes below that test it. FooTest uses regular test methods, no dataProviders. BarTest uses dataProvider methods with @codeCoverageIgnore annotations and BazTest uses dataProvider methods with no annotations.

You can see how the code coverage score is lower with BazTest.

[image: Terminal screenshot of phpunit invocation.]

[image: Code Coverage report screenshot with all test classes.]

[image: Code Coverage report screenshot with BazTest detail.]

Foo.php

```
namespace phpunittestproject\src;


/**
 * Foo
 * 
 * This is a simple class to be used as a source file
 * in unit test experiments. It gets and sets a name
 * string and date object.
 *
 */
class Foo
{



    /**
     * Name
     * 
     * String characters other than numeric.
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $name = null;

    /**
     * Date
     * 
     * Date no older than 2000.
     * 
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $date = null;


    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * Sets instance vars.
     * 
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->name = '';
        $this->date = new \DateTime('now');

    }


    /**
     * Get Date
     * 
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Get Name
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set Date
     * 
     * This method accepts a DateTime object that corresponds
     * to a date no earlier than 2000.
     * 
     * @param \DateTime $value Date after 2000.
     * @return boolean Result of operation.
     */
    public function setDate(\DateTime $value)
    {
        if($value < new \DateTime('2000-01-01 00:00:00')){
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->date = $value;
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set Name
     * 
     * This method accepts a string that does not contain numeric
     * characters.
     * 
     * @param string $value String without numeric characters.
     * @return boolean Result of operation.
     */
    public function setName(string $value)
    {
        if(preg_match('/\\d/', $value)){
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->name = $value;
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

FooTest.php:

```
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace phpunittestproject\test;

use \phpunittestproject\src\Foo;

/**
 * 
 * Foo Test
 * 
 * This test class does not use dataProvider methods. All
 * test assertions are being done in test metods.
 *
 */
class FooTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{


    /**
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function testGetDate()
    {
        $foo = new Foo();

        // Good date:
        $date = new \DateTime('2011-01-01 11:11:11');
        $foo->setDate($date);
        $this->assertEquals($date, $foo->getDate());

        // Bad date:
        $date = new \DateTime('1990-01-01 11:11:11');
        $foo->setDate($date);
        $this->assertNotEquals($date, $foo->getDate());

    }

    /**
     *
     * 
     */
    public function testGetName()
    {
        $foo = new Foo();

        // Good name:
        $foo->setName('A Good Name');
        $this->assertEquals('A Good Name', $foo->getName());

        // Bad name:
        $foo->setName('Bad Name 666');
        $this->assertNotEquals('Bad Name 666', $foo->getName());

    }

    /**
     * Test setDate()
     * 
     * This test method tests the date property when it is
     * set with good and bad data using method setDate().
     * 
     */
    public function testSetDate()
    {
        $foo = new Foo();

        // Good date:
        $date = new \DateTime('2011-01-01 11:11:11');
        $foo->setDate($date);
        $this->assertAttributeEquals($date, 'date', $foo);

        // Bad date:
        $date = new \DateTime('1990-01-01 11:11:11');
        $foo->setDate($date);
        $this->assertAttributeNotEquals($date, 'date', $foo);

    }

    /**
     *
     * Test setName()
     * 
     * This test method tests the name property when it is
     * set with good and bad data using method setName().
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function testSetName()
    {
        $foo = new Foo();

        // Good name:
        $foo->setName('Good Name');
        $this->assertAttributeEquals('Good Name', 'name', $foo);

        // Bad name:
        $foo->setName('Bad Name 666');
        $this->assertAttributeNotEquals('', 'name', $foo);

    }

}
```

BarTest.php:

```
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace phpunittestproject\test;

use \phpunittestproject\src\Foo;

/**
 * 
 * Bar Test
 * 
 * This test class utilizes dataProvider methods to feed
 * test methods. The dataProvider methods are annotated
 * with codeCoverageIgnore.
 * 
 */
class BarTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{


    /**
     * 
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function providerTestSetDateWithInvalidData()
    {
        return array(
                array(new \DateTime('1990-01-01 11:11:11')),
        );
    }

    /**
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function providerTestSetDateWithValidData()
    {
        return array(
                array(new \DateTime('2011-01-01 11:11:11')),
        );
    }

    /**
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function providerTestSetNameWithInvalidData()
    {
        return array(
                array('Bad Name 666'),              
        );
    }

    /**
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function providerTestSetNameWithValidData()
    {
        return array(
                array('Good Name'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function testGetDate()
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $date = new \DateTime('2001-01-01 11:11:11');
        $foo->setDate($date);
        $this->assertEquals($date, $foo->getDate());
    }

    /**
     *
     * 
     */
    public function testGetName()
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->setName('A Good Name');
        $this->assertEquals('A Good Name', $foo->getName());
    }

    /**
     *
     * @dataProvider providerTestSetDateWithInvalidData
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function testSetDateWithInvalidData($value)
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->setDate($value);
        $this->assertAttributeNotEquals($value, 'date', $foo);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @dataProvider providerTestSetDateWithValidData
     *
     *
     */
    public function testSetDateWithValidData($value)
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->setDate($value);
        $this->assertAttributeEquals($value, 'date', $foo);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @dataProvider providerTestSetNameWithInvalidData
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function testSetNameWithInvalidData($value)
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->setName($value);
        $this->assertAttributeNotEquals($value, 'name', $foo);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @dataProvider providerTestSetNameWithValidData
     *
     *
     */
    public function testSetNameWithValidData($value)
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->setName($value);
        $this->assertAttributeEquals($value, 'name', $foo);
    }

}
```

BazTest.php:

```
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace phpunittestproject\test;

use \phpunittestproject\src\Foo;


/**
 * 
 * Baz Test
 * 
 * This test class utilizes dataProvider methods to feed
 * test methods. The dataProvider methods are not annotated
 * with codeCoverageIgnore.
 *
 */
class BazTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{


    /**
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function providerTestSetDateWithInvalidData()
    {
        return array(
                array(new \DateTime('1990-01-01 11:11:11')),
        );
    }

    /**
     *
     * 
     */
    public function providerTestSetDateWithValidData()
    {
        return array(
                array(new \DateTime('2011-01-01 11:11:11')),
        );
    }

    /**
     *
     * 
     */
    public function providerTestSetNameWithInvalidData()
    {
        return array(
                array('Bad Name 666'),              
        );
    }

    /**
     *
     * 
     */
    public function providerTestSetNameWithValidData()
    {
        return array(
                array('Good Name'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function testGetDate()
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $date = new \DateTime('2001-01-01 11:11:11');
        $foo->setDate($date);
        $this->assertEquals($date, $foo->getDate());
    }

    /**
     *
     * 
     */
    public function testGetName()
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->setName('A Good Name');
        $this->assertEquals('A Good Name', $foo->getName());
    }

    /**
     *
     * @dataProvider providerTestSetDateWithInvalidData
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function testSetDateWithInvalidData($value)
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->setDate($value);
        $this->assertAttributeNotEquals($value, 'date', $foo);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @dataProvider providerTestSetDateWithValidData
     *
     *
     */
    public function testSetDateWithValidData($value)
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->setDate($value);
        $this->assertAttributeEquals($value, 'date', $foo);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @dataProvider providerTestSetNameWithInvalidData
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function testSetNameWithInvalidData($value)
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->setName($value);
        $this->assertAttributeNotEquals($value, 'name', $foo);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @dataProvider providerTestSetNameWithValidData
     *
     *
     */
    public function testSetNameWithValidData($value)
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->setName($value);
        $this->assertAttributeEquals($value, 'name', $foo);
    }

}
```

phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="DataProviderTestSuite">
            <file>phpunittestproject/test/FooTest.php</file>
            <file>phpunittestproject/test/BarTest.php</file>
            <file>phpunittestproject/test/BazTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <file>phpunittestproject/test/FooTest.php</file>
            <file>phpunittestproject/test/BarTest.php</file>
            <file>phpunittestproject/test/BazTest.php</file>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the test files from your whitelist. You don't do code coverage on your tests themselves, its meant to tell you what parts of your application code your tests cover.

Comment: That solved it Christopher thanks! I edited the phpunit.xml file so that the whitelist file elements were replaced by a single element `<file>phpunittestproject/src/Foo.php</file>`. So awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Christopher for the solution! A misconfigured phpunit.xml file was causing PhpUnit to test the tests. Editing the whitelist elements fixed the low code coverage score. The dataProvider methods do not need to be annotated with @codeCoverageIgnore!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="DataProviderTestSuite">
            <!-- Test files go here: -->
            <file>phpunittestproject/test/FooTest.php</file>
            <file>phpunittestproject/test/BarTest.php</file>
            <file>phpunittestproject/test/BazTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <!-- Source files to be tested go here: -->
            <file>phpunittestproject/src/Foo.php</file>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

[image: Code coverage HTML report with 100% score.]